# Switch React parent component without unmounting child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I wish to change a parent component from `<View />` to `<SafeAreaView />` without unmounting the contained child class.

```
// App

<SafeView>
  <MainNavigator />
</SafeView>
```

```
// SafeView component

class SafeView extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { children, showSafeView } = this.props;
    const Component = showSafeView ? SafeAreaView : View;
    return (
      <Component style={styles.view} key="test_component">
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} key="test_view">
          { children }
        </View>
      </Component>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ showSafeView: state.navigation.safe });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SafeView);
```

The observed behaviour is:

1. The "showSafeView props updates
2. The parent component changes
3. The child component unmounts
4. The child component mounts

You can see that I'm using `props.children`, but I have also tried passing the child component directly as a prop, with the same result:

```
<SafeView Child={MainNavigator} />

///

const { Child, showSafeView } = this.props;
const Component = showSafeView ? SafeAreaView : View;
return (
  <Component style={styles.view} key="test_component">
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} key="test_view">
      <Child key="test_child" />
    </View>
  </Component>
```

Comment: You're toggling between `SafeAreaView` and `View`. It's a normal behavior that they will mount/unmount. What is your goal here? keep both components mounted showing only once at a time?

Comment: @Dupocas I want to change between having View / SafeAreaView as the parent component, without remounting the child component.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible. Everytime  the parent unmounts, it's children will unmount too. You're not reusing the same instance of `Child`. It's just two different components that happens to includes `Child` as `children`. But why would you need such a weird use case? Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? What is the purpose of maintaining a child rendered and change it's parent?

Comment: @Dupocas I have an application in which a subset of pages require SafeAreaView, and I was hoping to find a general wrapper solution to avoid including SafeAreaView in each of these specific cases.